# Running 2560x1440 with nVidia 525m on Dell XPS L502X

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, high-resolution

I'm trying to get a Dell Studio XPS L502X to run an external 27" monitor via the HDMI port running off an nVidia GeForce GT525m.  This is the native resolution of the monitor.

The highest resolution available, without adjusting any advanced settings, is 1920x1080, far less than ideal for this ample display.  I can add a custom resolution in the nVidia control panel (after accepting a nasty warning), but it becomes highly unstable.

It won't boot past the Windows login screen unless I disconnect the display and do a hard reboot.  Other times, it doesn't get past the BIOS screen.  I ran a system restore on a point before the display was connected and all is good.

There are lot of additional obscure configurations I'm not entirely familiar with (active pixels, front porch, sync width, total pixels, polarity, refresh) in the custom resolution settings.  Is there some combination of these settings that will enable to function reliably at this resolution or it this just expecting too much from the GPU?

**EDIT** ... I should add that I have tried connecting the display like so:

`laptop > HDMI > monitor`

`laptop > miniDP > adapter > DVI > monitor`

In either configuration, it won't automatically provide an option for higher than 1920x1080.

I am also connecting a second monitor.  The laptop is designed and able to drive two external displays and the internal display simultaneously.

**EDIT 2** ... already updated to latest drivers.

Comment: Update your Nvidia drivers to the latest and see if it will auto detect. Also did you Test the custom resolution before using it in the Nvidia Control Panel? And your GPU supports that resolution so you aren't expecting too much from it.

Comment: It probably all needs to be HDMI 1.4-capable... 'puter, cable & monitor. Otherwise try it with DVI or Display Port without adaptors.

Comment: @RsyaStudios: already updated the drivers.  It would appear that the GPU will "support" it but may not entirely *support* it.

Comment: @Tetsujin: thanks, that's the next step.  I'll need to grab a `miniDP -> standardDP` cable instead of the `miniDP -> DVI` adapter that's there now.

Comment: That's how I got my Dell 2713s both going nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution was to use a DisplayPort cable with no adapters.** (`miniDP > standardDP` cable)

The system immediately recognized the QHD native resolution.  Windows spent some time fussing over screen detection, but I eventually got it working reliably.